# Usar Token metodo GET WebAPI HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Meu problema é o seguinte: estou consumindo um WebAPI com o método `PostAsJsonAsync` Nesta chamada estou recebendo um Token para autenticação nos metodos ADMIN de uma plataforma EAD que estamos trabalhando.

Até aqui tudo certo. Quando chamo os métodos ADMIN enviando o Token retornado no método de login, esta retornando como "Não autorizado". Segue parte do código que não esta funcionando:

```
response = null;                     
vAuth_token = retorno.authentication_token;

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-Auth-Token", vAuth_token);

response = await client.GetAsync("api/admin/users");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
  //HTTP GET
  try
  {
    Usuarios usuarios = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Usuarios>();
  }
  catch (Exception erro)
  {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Samuel está completamente certo. Para lhe dar mais informação, entenda que:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization
```

é equivalente a:

```
HTTP/1.1
Authorization: <tipo> <token>
```

O `DefaultRequestHeaders` é uma coleção de chaves e valores, igual um `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. Assim, o seguinte é exatamente igual ao anterior:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "<tipo> <token>");
```

Se desejar algo assim:

```
HTTP/1.1
X-Auth-Token: <qualquer coisa>
```

Teria que usar igual o @SamuelMcAravey falou, que seria:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", "<qualquer coisa>");
```

Mais informações sobre as cabeçalhas de HTTP (HTTP Headers) pode ser encontrado em vários fontes na internet, [esse artigo do Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_campos_de_cabe%C3%A7alho_HTTP) sendo um deles.

Comment: Obrigado brazilianldsjaguar, mas continua com o mesmo problema. Não sei se eu não entendi direito. Onde estava com problema troquei por client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", vAuth_token); . Será que falta mais alguma coisa?

Answer (score 3):

A problema está aqui:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("X-Auth-Token", vAuth_token);
```

O que acontece é que o header de HTTP vira algo assim:

```
Authorization: X-Auth-Token <<seu token aqui>>
```

Quando você está construindo o AuthenticationHeaderValue o primeiro parâmetro é chamado scheme. Vocé veja isto usado bastante para Bearer Authentication, mas eu acho que você esta querendo que seja só um header normal. Para fazer isto você pode tentar algo assim:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", vAuth_token);
```

E daí você vai ver um header assim que deve funcionar:

```
X-Auth-Token: <<seu token>>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Samuel McAravey, mas continua com o mesmo problema. Não sei se eu não entendi direito. Onde estava com problema troquei por client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", vAuth_token); . Será que falta mais alguma coisa?

Answer (score 1):

Eu precisava primeiro chamar a página de login com o Token para logar, e depois chamo os método ADMIN.

Resolução:

```
if (retorno.valid == "true") {
response = null;
client = null;
vAuth_token = retorno.authentication_token;

client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/login?auth_token=" + vAuth_token, "");

response = null;
client = null;
client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Auth-Token", vAuth_token);
response = await client.GetAsync("api/admin/users");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    // HTTP GET
    try
    {
        //Usuarios usuarios = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Usuarios>();
        var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {

    }
}
```

Obrigado !

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Desculpe por não ter fornecido mais informações, mas não estava ciente dessas outras informações! =D Recomendo aceitar uma dessas respostas (pode ser a sua mesma :P)